# Magento 2 For what secureUrlList at di

Tags: magento2, di.xml

What purpose of using secureUrlList at Magento di.xml?
It appear at few di.xml base and for frontend:

Like an example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="secureUrlList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="contact" xsi:type="string">/contact/</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is list of url prefix that will use secure base url setting. See [\Magento\Framework\Url::_isSecure](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Url.php#L357) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the parameter "**secureUrlLis**t" defines an array of urls, that should be secure, so that means the url from this list will start from **"https://"** if secure URL is enabled.